# Qual a maneira mais correta de configurar o corpo da página antes de começar a estilizar os demais elementos?

Tags: layout

Estou iniciando um projeto e estou com uma dúvida, qual a melhor maneira de configurar o corpo da página antes de estilizar os demais elementos? além do corpo da página vocês utilizam uma `div` por exemplo como uma espécie de `container` para todo o site ou começam a produzir direto no corpo do site?

```
<body>

  <div id="tudo">

  </div>

</body>
```

E como configurar o corpo da página da maneira correta pra receber um site de Layout Elástico?

Comment: Não precisa de um div pro "tudo". Já tem o `<body>` pra isso

Comment: Eu não sei se é a maneira mais correta, mas eu já prefiro colocar uma <div> logo abaixo do <body> envelopando todo o conteúdo.
Como você fez.
Acho que no final não há muita diferença. Confesso que não sei se é o correto.

Comment: É por que a maioria dos tutoriais que vejo os desenvolvedores usam.

Comment: Sim pode usar bem de boa, é até melhor para quando for trabalhar com php e fazer tratamentos de div e quem sabe fazer conteúdo ser atualizado sem precisar atualizar a página e com div como container isso fica mais fácil de fazer é sim uma boa prática.

Comment: Algumas destas respostas lhe atenderam?

Answer (score 0):

A `<div id="tudo">` pode sim ser usada como corpo da página para quem sabe você fazer o site responsivo e tudo o que estiver dentro dele também.

E outra coisa que pode ser feita é centralizar a DIV pra deixar o site centralizado.

```
#tudo{
 width: 1024px;
 height:768px;
 margin: auto;  
}
```

Ou fazer assim:

```
#tudo{
  width: 100%;
}

<div id="tudo">

</div>
```

E tudo o que estiver dentro da div precisaria fazer a conversão de Pixel para % e o tamanho da fonte fazer de Pixel para EM.

```
px  em  porcento
5px     0.3125em    31.25%
6px     0.3750em    37.50%
7px     0.4375em    43.75%
8px     0.5000em    50.00%
9px     0.5625em    56.25%
10px    0.6250em    62.50%
11px    0.6875em    68.75%
12px    0.7500em    75.00%
13px    0.8125em    81.25%
14px    0.8750em    87.50%
15px    0.9375em    93.75%
```

Lembrando que isso é apenas um exemplo mas responde sua pergunta, pode sim fazer dentro de uma div.

Comment: Maicon, como faço essa conversão de px pra %? Do que tiver dentro da div

Comment: Tem um site http://pxtoem.com/ que faz isso pra você, você coloca o tamanho em pixel do container e depois logo abaixo você coloca o tamanho do que você quer em Pixel e ele vai dar o tamanho em EM que pode ser usado também.

Comment: Achei meio redundante os dois valores de pixels.

Comment: É que o primeiro é como se fosse o tamanho do container e o outro em baixo seria pra informar o tamanho da div que quer criar dentro do container e ai ele vai passar pra você o tamanho em EM para ai sim ele se adequar dentro do container.

Comment: Mais ele vai me dar o valor em em. Funciona da mesma forma que a %?

Comment: Sim funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Costumo organizar da seguinte forma quando posso utilizar algum `framework` como `twitter-bootstrap`:

- Crio um header utilazando a tag `<header>`.
- Crio uma `<div>` onde conterá a informação/produto do site.

  - Dentro desta div crio as `divs` separam os conteudos dos sites (como menu lateral, anúncios e conteúdo).
- Crio um footer utilizando a tag `<footer>`.

**Obs:** dentro de cada componente deste coloco as `divs` juntamente com as classes que fazem o site ser responsivo.

Código base:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="profile" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="conteudo" class="col-md-8 span7 text-center">
                </div>
                <div id="artigos" class="col-md-4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="text-center">
        rodapé
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Mas eu não queria usar o Bootstrap, não quero fazer pra mobile, meu objetivo é fazer um site que não fique aquelas bordas vazias na tela.

Comment: bootstrap funciona pra sites normais e mobile, pra não ficar com as bordas substitua: `container` por container`-fluid`.